# SQL query select matched and absent values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two MySQL tables:

```
user(id, name)
cards(id, number, user_id)
```

I need to form query which will allow to show on page which cards are owned by which user or not owned by anybody yet (user_name - card_number)

**NOTES**:

1. One card can be linked only to single user
2. One user can have more than one card
3. I need also show cards which not linked to any user yet (so user name will be 'NONE'), their user_id = 0 in cards table_id

I have tried:

```
SELECT c.id, c.number, u.name FROM card AS c, user AS u WHERE c.user_id=u.id
```

This allow me to select cards which are linked with users

But I am still in trouble how to add there cards whose user_id = 0 (remember I need to set 'NONE' value for user name for this case).

UPDATE: There is no user id = 0 in users table

Comment: So basically, you want a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Is there a user_id of 0 in your user table?

Comment: Joel Hinz, possibly, I am still not too well with SQL;
Andrew, no, and service is still under development, so we can add such changes if need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`. This will return `NULL` for the columns in the joined table when the first table doesn't have any matching rows.

```
SELECT c.id, c.number, IFNULL(u.name, "not linked") AS name
FROM card AS c
LEFT JOIN user as U ON c.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works exactly as I need, have already tested it on my demo data